# akka-http responding with outgoing response if failed

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I am calling external API and I would like to return the result "AS IS" to user in case of status code different than **OK** :

```
val connectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] =
  Http().outgoingConnection("akka.io")
def responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Source.single(HttpRequest(uri = "/"))
    .via(connectionFlow)
    .runWith(Sink.head)

val fooRoutes = path("foo"){
get {
complete(
responseFuture.flatMap{ response =>
case OK => 
Unmarshal(response.entity.withContentType(ContentTypes.`application/json`)).to[Foo]
case _ => response //fails 
})}}
```

how can I return the response "AS IS" in case of status code other than OK without doing something like :

```
 Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String].flatMap { body =>
Future.failed(new IOException(s"The response status is ${response.status} response body is $body"))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon there might be different valid ways of solving this, one could be using the `onComplete` directive:

```
  val fooRoutes = path("foo"){
    get {
      onComplete(responseFuture) {
        case Success(response) if response.status == OK =>
          complete(Unmarshal(response.entity.withContentType(ContentTypes.`application/json`)).to[Foo])

        case Success(response) => complete(response)
        case Failure(ex)    => complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a valid solution.